# What set has a monster food truck with a burger on top?

Tags: set-identification

I saw this image of a Lego truck with a giant burger on top, but the set number was not given. If anyone could tell me what set this is, I'd appreciate it!

[image: Truck with big burger on top and a small burger included]

Comment: I have just realized that I could've simply typed "lego burger truck" into Google and I would find my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the Creator 3-in-1 [Monster Burger Truck](https://brickset.com/sets/31104-1/Monster-Burger-Truck), set number 31104. It has a piece count of 499, and it sells on LEGO.com for $49.99. It was released in January 2020.

Comment: What about the price in Euros? Or will I have to find that out myself?

Comment: No, I just figured it out.  It's 54.99 Euros.